# CodeIgniter protect sensitive data in HTML when user leaves browser open

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, security

I have a problem and after some research online was unable to find other people with this same issue.

I'm designing a site that has sensitive data the user's work with in the page content. It uses CodeIgniter as well as CodeIgniter's session and cookie implementations to track user activity and determine when a session has expired. when sessions expire, the user has to log in again either through a sign-in portal or through a sign-in popup.

My issue is if someones working on their computer then just gets up and walks away from the browser, the session expires, but they didn't realize the session would expire then return to their computer to finish their work. There is a regular ajax call that checks if the user has been inactive, and if the time threshold is reached their session data will be erased and the session is no longer active. There is then a popup window prompting the user to sign in again if they want to keep working.

The problem is, how do I protect any sensitive data in the HTML in the meantime? You might think if the session expires just redirect the user away from the page, but if they're in the middle of something I don't want to erase all of their work. I could try just hiding the HTML using javascript, but then someone could just open the inspector to see the HTML. is there some way I could prevent anyone from seeing the page data at all unless the sign in a popup is completed?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anyway to protect their work like you're asking.

I'd suggest saving the users work in a draft format, as they enter it. Then if they walk away and get logged out it doesn't matter, the work is still there when they log on next.